# Failed to build iOS project. ReactNative Cocoapods (M1 Mac)

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

info Found Xcode workspace "test.xcworkspace"
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace test.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme test -destination id=FBBF8750-4AB7-45C3-B382-02B30CBDADF9")
(node:94702) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening test.xcworkspace.
Command line invocation:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace test.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme test -destination id=FBBF8750-4AB7-45C3-B382-02B30CBDADF9

User defaults from command line:
IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Build settings from command line:
TOOLCHAINS = com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault

note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Constructing build description
note: Build preparation complete
CreateBuildDirectory /Users/sazzadkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cjhxwlbrhikcboeqmixuohsiccis/Build/Intermediates.noindex
cd /Users/sazzadkhan/Documents/apps/test/ios
builtin-create-build-directory /Users/sazzadkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cjhxwlbrhikcboeqmixuohsiccis/Build/Intermediates.noindex

CreateBuildDirectory /Users/sazzadkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cjhxwlbrhikcboeqmixuohsiccis/Build/Products
cd /Users/sazzadkhan/Documents/apps/test/ios
builtin-create-build-directory /Users/sazzadkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cjhxwlbrhikcboeqmixuohsiccis/Build/Products

CreateBuildDirectory /Users/sazzadkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cjhxwlbrhikcboeqmixuohsiccis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
cd /Users/sazzadkhan/Documents/apps/test/ios
builtin-create-build-directory /Users/sazzadkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cjhxwlbrhikcboeqmixuohsiccis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator

CreateBuildDirectory /Users/sazzadkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cjhxwlbrhikcboeqmixuohsiccis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libevent
cd /Users/sazzadkhan/Documents/apps/test/ios
builtin-create-build-directory /Users/sazzadkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cjhxwlbrhikcboeqmixuohsiccis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libevent

CreateBuildDirectory /Users/sazzadkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cjhxwlbrhikcboeqmixuohsiccis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/boost-for-react-native
cd /Users/sazzadkhan/Documents/apps/test/ios
builtin-create-build-directory /Users/sazzadkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cjhxwlbrhikcboeqmixuohsiccis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/boost-for-react-native

CreateBuildDirectory /Users/sazzadkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cjhxwlbrhikcboeqmixuohsiccis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog
cd /Users/sazzadkhan/Documents/apps/test/ios
builtin-create-build-directory /Users/sazzadkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cjhxwlbrhikcboeqmixuohsiccis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog

CreateBuildDirectory /Users/sazzadkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cjhxwlbrhikcboeqmixuohsiccis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit
cd /Users/sazzadkhan/Documents/apps/test/ios
builtin-create-build-directory /Users/sazzadkhan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cjhxwlbrhikcboeqmixuohsiccis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit

this error happens three times this week last night it was working fine but when i run build again it got this error

**EDIT:** I fixed this already... For those who have this error its just an update of cocoa pods.. you just have to wait a few hours or even a day and it will work again... If you waited for a day and its not fixed yet its probably a error from yours... Try deleting node_modules, then `npm install` / `yarn install`. then go to ios folder and then `pod install` if it doesnt work try making a fresh react native project and then transfer your code and dont forget to transfer your packages aswell... dont transfer your packages by by copy pasting package.json and transfer just npm install the packages manually

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? The project is building well from Xcode, but seeing `CreateBuildDirectory` lines from terminal and then script exits with code 1 with any traceable error.

Comment: i did fix it :)